# Error while creating new Laravel project using Composer

Tags: php, laravel, macos

I'm new to Laravel and trying to create a new clean project using composer, but keep getting an error I can't seem to solve.

When I create a new project, using composer in `/htdocs` with `composer create-project laravel/laravel example`, the installer is busy for a while but then gives me an error. This is the terminal output:

```
Writing lock file
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover

In Filesystem.php line 122:

  file_put_contents(): Exclusive locks are not supported for this stream


Script @php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

I am using Mac with a clean install of the newest version of Composer. PHP version is also newest.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: have you configured composer propperly ?

Comment: Composer was installed correctly and newest version. I've now tried installing MAMP instead of XAMPP, and that seems to be working okay. Also, if I execute the new project command on a folder other than /htdocs, the project installs fine. So no idea what the problem is, but this works for me. Thanks for replying

Answer (score -1):

Try updating composer with

```
composer self-update
```